# Whatsapp type edit button IOS master detail app

Tags: ios, iphone, edit, master-detail

I am developing an application using the master detail template. Here i have 'edit' and 'add' buttons by default. Can anyone please guide me how to change the default edit button to a edit button with border image, like that in whatsapp and oblige.

Comment: What methods have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
UIImage* image_bk = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatsAPP_image.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image_bk.size.width, image_bk.size.height);
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image_bk forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editAction)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *customEditButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=customEditButton;
```

Comment: Are image3 and image_bk both same?

Comment: hi, i want to retain the default functionality!! Plz suggest how to do